# Python event binding with tkinter

Tags: events, binding, python-3.x, tkinter, key

So guys I'm new to GUIs in Python and I've been trying to understand the envents process, here's my code, and the intention that whenever I press the 'a' key it should print "key pressed'. But it won't work for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*-coding:UTF-8 -*

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(event):
    print("key pressed")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=100, height=100, bg='blue')
canvas.bind("a", callback)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't execute the callback function because the focus of the program is on the `Tk` element. If you replace that line with `root.bind("a", callback)`, it will work as you expect.

The problem is that the canvas element doesn't receive the focus when you click on it like other widgets as Entry, so it will only respond to keydown events if you call first `canvas.focus_set()`.

Comment: Note that you can also bind `<1>` to do the `focus_set`, which will allow you to click in the canvas and then type a character.