# Enabling/disabling fullscreen and maximize window with a keypress in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to enable/disable fullscreen and maximized window (--zoomed) in Python 3.x using Tkinter.
This is my code

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()

def fullscreen_on(event):
  tk.attributes(--fullscreen, True), repr.event.F11

def fullscreen_off(event):
 tk.attributes(--fullscreen, False), repr.event.Escape


photo = PhotoImage(file="image.GIF")
image_label=Label(tk, image=photo)
image_label.grid(row=0, column=2)


tk.mainloop()
```

It shows the image, but i can't zoom/enable fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining callbacks not binding them to anything in your application.  To get a callback to react it needs to be bound  to an event (e.g. `tk.bind ("<Key>", callback)` )

Please have a look on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=event%20tkinter#bindings-and-events) of event / event-binding.

You can bind the event like shown [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153715/python-event-binding-with-tkinter).

What is it you want to do using repr.event.F11 / repr.event.Escape? print something?

Please make sure to fix your indentation.

You can also bind `F11` and `Escape` to your callbacks using

- `tk.bind("<F11>", fullscreen_on)`
- `tk.bind("<Escape>", fullscreen_off)`

Comment: Thank you. I used repr.event because i made a mistake in reading a tutorial. Finally i used                                                                                                    'def fullscreen_on(event):
    tk.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

def fullscreen_off(event):
    tk.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    

tk.bind("<F11>", fullscreen_on)
tk.bind("<Escape>", fullscreen_off)'